# Millennial Media is not working after adding flurry SDK in android

Tags: android, flurry, millennial-media

I am trying to use Millennial Media and Flurry SDK in the same android app.
Both are working individually (tested individually) but showing error when trying to initialize Millennial Media SDK and both SDK's are included.

Showing error in the below line,

```
MMSDK.initialize(this);
```

In the proguard file i have added,

```
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Google Play Services library
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *

-keepclassmembernames class * {
@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
}

#If you are using the Google Mobile Ads SDK, add the following:
# Preserve GMS ads classes
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**


#If you are using the InMobi SDK, add the following:
# Preserve InMobi Ads classes
-keep class com.inmobi.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.inmobi.**
#If you are using the Millennial Media SDK, add the following:
# Preserve Millennial Ads classes
-keep class com.millennialmedia.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.millennialmedia.**
```

And error showing in logcat,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have too many classes. Enable multidex in project gradle.